# The purpose of the distance_type in a custom iterator - std::distance(first, last) will return a wrong result, if first and last are too far way

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, c++14

I want to implement an iterator for a custom class

```
template</*...*/>
class foo
{
public:
    using value_type = /* depends on template parameters */;
    using size_type = /* depends on template parameters */;

    class iterator
        : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, value_type, /* some suitable difference_type compatible to size_type */>
    {
    public:
        iterator(foo& bar, size_type i)
            : m_bar(bar), m_i(i),
              m_dereferenceable(i != bar.size())
        { }

    private:
        foo& m_bar;
        size_type m_i;
        bool m_dereferenceable;
    };

    size_type size() const { /* ... */ }
    value_type operator[](size_type) { /* ... */ }
};
```

and wonder how I should implement `operator+=(difference_type)`. I've defined the `difference_type` to be `std::make_signed_t<size_type>` cause that makes perfect sense to me.

The crucial point is the following thing: I thought it would be plausible to define `m_i` to be of type `size_type`, ensure its value is clamped to `[0, m_bar.size()]` and use the flag `m_dereferenceable` to handle the case where an `iterator` with `m_i == 0` is decremented.

That's somehow complicated and everything would be easier, if I would change the type of `m_i` to the signed type `difference_type`. However, that would prevent me from iterating over the whole range, if `m_bar`'s size is exploiting the full range of `size_type`.

Now, I've realized that (for example) `std::distance`'s return type is `difference_type`. On the one hand, that's plausible cause we could have negative distances. On the other hand, if `m_bar`'s size is exploiting the full range of `size_type`, `std::distance` might return a wrong result.

> So, the question is: Taking in mind that (for example) `std::distance` might return wrong results, if I define `m_i` to be of type `size_type`, should I simply use `difference_type` instead (and benefit from an easier implementation)?

---

**EDIT:** Let me stress the following: Suppose we have a `vector x` with `vector = std::vector</* ... */>` and perform `x.resize(std::numeric_limits<vector::size_type>::max())`.

Since the type of `d = std::distance(x.begin(), x.end())` is `vector::difference_type` and the type of `s = x.size()` is `vector::size_type`, I'm curious whether or not `d` will be equal to `s`.

This question isn't about `vector`, it's a question about the whole concept of a `size_type`, a `difference_type` and their purpose for an iterator.

Please ignore any technical issue (memory adressing, etc.) and think of a `size_type` as a "complicated thing" (i.e. an abstraction of what one understands of a "size" representation).

Clearly, `d` must be of a signed type cause we might have negative distances. And sure, I can think of technical issues which prevented the standard from guaranteeing that a `difference_type` object must be able to store a `size_type` object. But since the STL is all about generic programming, I'm surprised.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t

Comment: @MaxLybbert I cannot use `ptrdiff_t` cause `size_type` might be a complicated thing.

Comment: Sorry; I read `size_type` as `size_t`.

Comment: Note, on x86 (x64 inclusive) you can't use instructions with relative addressing with offset greater then `std::int32_t` (i.e. +-2G).

Comment: @Orient Again, `size_type` might be a "complicated thing", i.e. an abstraction of what one understands of a "size" representation.

Comment: If `size_type` is anything but an integral or enumeration type, that `make_signed_t` is UB.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, replace `std::make_signed_t` by "some suitable `difference_type` compatible to `size_type`".

Comment: If `size_type` is a complicated thing that represents "size", then why would the signed version of `size_type` not have effectively the same range?  In practice, exploiting the full range of `size_type` if `distance_type` has less range in either signed direction can cause bugs.  In theory, containers should know this, and state that their max size is `size_type(-1)/2` or somesuch, or even `max_distance_type`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `size_type`  and `difference_type` are just typedefs of the containers allocators or iterators own typedefs. They are completely unrelated to the vector itself.

That aside i think you are overthinking this as a whole. `size_type` and `difference_type` are two conceptually different types:

**difference_type:**
*signed integer type representing the difference between the address of any two elements in a sequence*

**size_type:**
*unsigned integer type representing the length of a sequence*

Whenever you use a function that returns either one of those types, they return a value that coheres to it's definition. With `std::distance` are you *really* finding the size of the container? No, you are finding the difference between two iterators. With `std::size` you aren't finding any differences between iterators, you are retrieving a value which should make logical sense, an `unsigned` integer type which will represent the size of the container. This is simply a better representation than returning a `signed` type, as you are aware, the length of a container will always be positive.

So, you could get away with using only `difference_type`, after all you will always be able to safely calculate the size of a container using `std::distance`.

But should you?

`size_type` is simply a **representation** of an *unsigned* `difference_type`. It is nothing more, it is simply guaranteed to be able to hold a value representing the size of the container.

### The verdict

You can get away with typing less and omitting `size_type` from your code but i would strongly advise against it. It's part of the standard, and it makes logical sense. When you are calculating the difference two objects the result must be able to handle negatives, but size will never have that issue, so why should it be defined as `signed`.